# Selecting a sheet from another workbook's cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to select a sheet name in workbook1 called exactly as the cell's value ("K2") in Workbook2 and in a sheet called "GEO_MSCI_Indexes".

The idea is to have a dynamic reference to a worksheet in another workbook.

```
    Sub zzz()

Dim workbook2 As Workbook
Set workbook2 = Workbooks("Fondi non optica.xlsm")

Dim workbook1 As Workbook
Set workbook1 = Workbooks("MSCI Regional and Country Weights by Market Cap updated BD 2.xls")



workbook1.Sheets(Array(workbook2.Sheets("GEO_MSCI_Indexes").Range("K2").Value)).Select

        

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the value in cell K2?

Comment: Removing the Array would probably work assuming the value of K2 has the Worksheet name only. No idea why an Array was added here.

Comment: The value in K2 is December

Comment: So are you attempting to select a Sheet named "December" ? if so then Remove Array( ) from within Sheets in the last line.

Comment: You could lose the `Array(...)` part but the problem is probably that you have to make sure that the correct workbook is active: use `workbook1.Activate` before selecting the worksheet. But the question is why would you even want to select or activate. Take a look at [this legendary post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10717999) on how to avoid using `Select`.

Comment: `Array()` is not the issue here.  You haven't told us what the problem is though - what does your code do instead of work?

Comment: It simply does not work and returns the following error:
Run-time error '1004':
Select method of Sheets class failed

Comment: You can't select a sheet if it is hidden (or very hidden). Have you tried using `workbook1.Activate`?

Comment: It works, many thanks mate, but I did not quite the rationale behind it. Would you mind explaining?

Thanks again!

Comment: I hope you mean the `Activate` part. You cannot select a worksheet if its workbook isn't active. In the same way, you cannot select a range (cell) if its worksheet is not active. That's how `Select` works.